# conjure-up failed with "Exception: Could not determine Juju version."

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

The log file `~/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log`

```
2018-01-11 12:27:25,785 [DEBUG] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - juju.py:39 - bin_path candidate found
2018-01-11 12:27:25,785 [DEBUG] conjure-up/_unspecified_spell - juju.py:39 - wait_path candidate found
```

My `$PATH` has

```
db2adm@db2adm-ThinkPad-X230:~$ echo $PATH
/home/db2adm/bin:/home/db2adm/.local/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/snap:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin

db2adm@db2adm-ThinkPad-X230:~$ juju --version
2.3.1-xenial-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved with the following command:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

extracted from https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/1289

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`